# How to validate date in linux bash?

Tags: bash

I would like to validate the format of the date input (in `YYYY/MM/DD` format) and only allow the user to enter current date or date after it.

For example, if the user enters `2022/03/28` (before current date), then error message should appear. If the user enters `2022/04/01` (current date) or `2022/04/06` (after current date), then it will not show error message.

May I know how can I do the validation?

```
echo "Enter date (in YYYY/MM/DD format): " 
read date
```

Comment: As an aside, `MM/DD/YYYY` makes your job unnecessarily hard. `YYYY-MM-DD` is both standardized (ISO 8601) and easy to compare (because lexicographic order is identical to semantic order). It also avoids confusion between US and European users (the latter of whom are accustomed to `DD/MM/YYYY`).

Comment: Use a regular expression to match the format. Then use the `date` command to convert it to a format that's easily compared, such as `%s` for a numeric timestamp. Finally, compare that with the timestamp for today.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy THat's true, but MM/DD/YYYY is the format that most Americans are more used to. Software should accomodate users, not the other way around.

Comment: @Barmar, ...I'd buy the argument if it were just ease of sort order, but when the format also adds confusion by way of being incompatible with the convention used in the rest of the world with no visually obvious way to know which format was used to write any given date, it's just objectively bad. (`DD/MM/YYYY` is every bit as bad, for the same reasons).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Since when do Americans care what goes on in the rest of the world? :)

Comment: ...if you see `1/2/1983`, how do you know if it's January 2nd, or February 1st? I've seen someone deliberately use that confusion to slide something under the radar; choosing ambiguous representations is a decision that has very real consequences.

Comment: I will change the date format to `YYYY/MM/DD` as recommended by Charles

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me the code needs to perform two different validations:

- did the user enter a valid date (eg, `2020/10/40` is *not* a valid date)
- did the user enter a date that is earlier than today's date

For the 1st validation we can have `date` process the input as a date, eg:

```
$ input='2020/10/40'                     # invalid date
$ date -d "${input}"
date: invalid date ‘2020/10/40’
$ echo $?
1                                        # non-zero (false) return code

$ input='2020/10/20'                     # valid date
$ date -d "${input}"
Tue Oct 20 00:00:00 CDT 2020
$ echo $?
0                                        # zero (true) return code
```

For the 2nd validation we can let `bash` compare our dates as strings, eg:

```
$ input='2020/10/20'
$ today=$(date '+%Y/%m/%d')
$ typeset -p input today
declare -- input="2020/10/20"
declare -- today="2022/03/31"
$ [[ "${input}" < "${today}" ]] && echo 'error'
error

$ input='2022/03/31'
$ today=$(date '+%Y/%m/%d')
$ typeset -p input today
declare -- input="2022/03/31"
declare -- today="2022/03/31"
$ [[ "${input}" < "${today}" ]] && echo 'error'
          # no output

$ input='2022/05/31'
$ today=$(date '+%Y/%m/%d')
$ typeset -p input today
declare -- input="2022/05/31"
declare -- today="2022/03/31"
$ [[ "${input}" < "${today}" ]] && echo 'error'
          # no output
```

---

Pulling all of this into a demo:

```
today=$(date '+%Y/%m/%d')

while true
do
    echo "Enter date (in YYYY/MM/DD format): " 
    read input

    # validate input:

    date -d "${input}" > /dev/null 2>&1

    [[ $? != 0 ]]                                                            && \
    echo "ERROR: invalid date [${input}]; please try again."                 && \
    continue

    # compare input with today:

    [[ "${input}" < "${today}" ]]                                            && \
    echo "ERROR: input [${input}] is less than today [${today}]; try again." && \
    continue

    break
done

echo "Congrats! input [${input}] is greater-than/equal-to today [${today}]."
```

Testing:

```
Enter date (in YYYY/MM/DD format):
2020/10/40
ERROR: invalid date [2020/10/40]; please try again.
Enter date (in YYYY/MM/DD format):
2020/10/20
ERROR: input [2020/10/20] is less than today [2022/03/31]; try again.
Enter date (in YYYY/MM/DD format):
2022/03/20
ERROR: input [2022/03/20] is less than today [2022/03/31]; try again.
Enter date (in YYYY/MM/DD format):
2022/03/31
Congrats! input [2022/03/31] is greater-than/equal-to today [2022/03/31].

Enter date (in YYYY/MM/DD format):
2022/03/10
ERROR: input [2022/03/10] is less than today [2022/03/31]; try again.
Enter date (in YYYY/MM/DD format):
2022/05/31
Congrats! input [2022/05/31] is greater-than/equal-to today [2022/03/31].
```